# new Date(year,month,day) is deprecated

Tags: java, date, deprecated

I have a class `A_Class` which one of it's constructor parameters is of type `Date` and when I try to initialize an object of the class in my main for example:

```
A_Class aClass = new A_Class( param1, param2, new Date(1995,01,04) );
```

The IDE tells me that this format of `Date` is deprecated.

Isn't there another way of directly passing a new date to the constructor or do I always have to do it like this:

```
final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.US);
String dateInString1 = "1995-Jan-4";
Date dateInDate1 = formatter.parse(dateInString1);
A_Class aClass = new A_Class( param1, param2, dateInDate1 );
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Wrong class

You are using a terrible date-time class that is now legacy. Supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

## `LocalDate`

For a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 1995 , 1 , 5 ) ;
```

Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DD.

```
String output = localDate.toString() ;
```

Design your class to hold a `LocalDate` rather than a `Date`.

```
public class Employee 
{
    private String givenName, surName ;
    LocalDate whenHired ;

    // Constructor
    public Employee( String givenName , String surName , LocalDate whenHired ) 
    {
        …
    }

}
```

Example usage.

```
Employee alice = new Employee( "Alice" , "Anderson" , LocalDate.of( 1995 , Month.JANUARY , 4 ) ) ;
```

## Octal literal

> new Date(1995,01,04)

Do not start a literal integer with a zero unless you mean octal (base 8) rather than decimal (base 10).

Comment: I have never understood the pejorative language (from a number of people) used to malign Date and Calendar.  Did anyone have a better Date class in 1995?  Did anyone have a better Calendar class in 1996?  I certainly agree that one should use java.time instead, now, but when used correctly, Date and Calendar worked quite well.

Comment: @VGR Pejorative language becomes natural when you realize that `new Date(1995,01,04)` returns `Feb 4, 3895`, with both year and month being wrong. What idiot designs a Date class where year is 1900-based, month is 0-based, but day is 1-based? No consistency whatsoever. *Ludicrous!* --- Even `Calendar`, where year is fixed to be 0-based, still has 0-based month and 1-based day. No wonder they are both very error-prone to use.

Comment: @Andreas Sure, hindsight is easy now.  But in 1995, when C was dominant, it made sense (or seemed to make sense) for everything to be zero-based.  I’m just saying, no one complained about these issues at the time, because no one really knew better.  Designing date and calendar classes was fairly new territory.

Comment: @VGR Does it matter then?  JodaTime was the de facto standard from 2000-2014 and `java.time` is the standard now.

Comment: Can I pass ```LocaleDate.of(1995,1,5)``` as a parameter in my constructor?

Comment: @user007 Yes, if your constructor takes a `java.time.LocalDate` as parameter, not  `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @user007 Just change your `A_Class` to hold a `LocalDate` instead of a `Date`.

Comment: _"What idiot designs a Date class..."_ are we picking between James Gosling, Arthur van Hoff, and Alan Liu? or maybe there's some other candidate "idiot" who isn't named as an author in `java.util.Date`. ;-)

Comment: @VGR and others, Stack Overflow is not the place for this debate.